# Replacement for PyString_AS_STRING in python 3.x

Tags: python

In python 2.x versions there is a function named as **PyString_AS_STRING** to convert a pyobject pointer to a string or char pointer.

How can we achieve the same functionality in python 3?

Answer (score 2):

There's a PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE macro.

BTW: PyString_AS_STRING only works for string objects, returning a C string.

Comment: See also: [`PyUnicode_AS_DATA`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE)